# how to show the text of first textbox in second textbox?

Tags: .net, asp.net, textbox

I have two TextBoxes on my ASP.NET page:

1. Alt
2. Caption

When I have entered some text in Alt and after that on click on Caption I want to it to show the same text as was entered in Alt.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Best way to do it is using a JavaScript. Doing it in ASP on Postback would really make the site you're building slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hmm, you need to be more precise on how you want to do it as you have plenty of options here, e.g.

- On client-side using JavaScript, jQuery or [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html)

So, which way do you prefer?
**JavaScript** function:

```
function CaptionOnFocus() {
    document.getElementById('<%=Caption.ClientID%>').value = 
    document.getElementById('<%=Alt.ClientID%>').value;
}

<asp:TextBox ID="Caption" onfocus="CaptionOnFocus();" runat="server" />
```

**jQuery**:

```
$("#Caption").focus(function() {
  $("#Caption").val($(this).val());
});
```

- In the Server-side code. Set `AutoPostBack="True"` on **Caption** textbox control, use [OnGotFocus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9ht8161.aspx) event handler and, in it, copy the text to Caption, like so: `Caption.Text=Alt.Text`

Comment: The two text boxes can be set up in an ajax update panel also, to enable typing smoothly. However javascript would be the best :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript">

  function fillField() {
      document.getElementById('caption').value = document.getElementById('alt').value;
  }

</script>

<asp:TextBox id="caption" runat="server" onfocus="Javascript:fillField();" />
```